# Facebook returning random string instead of "state" param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, rubygems, omniauth

I am using Omniauth for Facebook connect in a Rails app. Facebook auth connects properly, but the "state" param - through which I should be able to pass data to retrieve on callback - is returning a string I can't decipher.

For example, authorizing through "/auth/facebook?display=popup&state=19422"

ends up returning a state of "ecae4f444fb248944083db0623c9a86f3f75dff36006be7e"

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `state` param is not supposed to be used to pass data around. That param is only to be used to stop [CSRF vulnerabilities](http://homakov.blogspot.pt/2012/07/saferweb-most-common-oauth2.html). That randomly generated string is being used in background to prevent those types of attacks.

You can pass your custom data by simply using any other param. OmniAuth is already kind enough to persist in the session any extra params you may send in your request.

So instead of passing data with

```
request_url?state=data
```

and getting it with

```
data = params[:state]
```

You can pass it with

```
request_url?whatever=data
```

and get it with

```
data = request.env['omniauth.params']['whatever']
```

And you can even omit the request and get the data with:

```
data = env['omniauth.params']['whatever']
```